# Gridview not showing date

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I'm working with a gridview, so i can show data from my three lists. I get it to show the title, but the date doesn't appear! Check the if statement.

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://knowitintranet:9797/sites/News"))
            {
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

                if (DropDownListNewsFeed.SelectedItem.Value == "All")
                {
                    SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

                    query.Lists = "<Lists>" +
                  "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("Staff News").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                  "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("Company News").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                  "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("Management News").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                  "</Lists>";


                    query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"Date\" />";
                    query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>";
                    query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

                    query.RowLimit = 10;

                    DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
                    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

                    GridViewNewsFeed.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                    GridViewNewsFeed.DataSource = dv;
                    GridViewNewsFeed.DataBind();

                    GridViewNewsFeed.AllowSorting = true;
                    GridViewNewsFeed.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListNewsFeed.SelectedItem.Value);

                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>";
                    query.RowLimit = 10;

                    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

                    RepeaterNewsFeed.DataSource = items;
                    RepeaterNewsFeed.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

My asp code:

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridViewNewsFeed" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" 
        CellSpacing="1" EnableModelValidation="True" GridLines="None">

        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ReadOnly="False"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ReadOnly="True"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[image: Here is a image of what my problem is.]

I was googling around, and i found [this site](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/137_How_to_format_DateTime_in_GridView_BoundColumn_and_TemplateColumn.aspx). But still don't getting it right.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get the date field in the datatable? Also, are you sure that the internal name of the field is Date.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the internal name of the Date field is something different. Try finding that and replace the Date in following line with the correct internal name:

```
"<FieldRef Name=\"Date\" />";
```

Also, use `Nullable=\"TRUE\`
setting the Nullable attribute to TRUE causes an empty value to be returned for lists that
do not include the Date column. The default is to skip a list that does not include the column.

Comment: Hm, isn't that the "column name" in this case it's Date. Or is it maybe Modified i should have there?

Comment: For a minute, change Date with Modified and see if the datatable is populated. The Date field may have a display name of Date but can have a different internal name.

Comment: with `query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Modified\" Nullable=\"TRUE\"/>";` i don't even get out title, but the exception is the same..

Comment: Did you change the DataField to Modified in the markup?

Comment: I've tried `<asp:BoundField DataField="Modified" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString = "{0:D}" HeaderText="Date" ReadOnly="True" />` but no output. Same exception.

Comment: one question. I get it to work if i choose 1 list in a time, to show title and date in a repeater control, is it possible to query through three lists at once and show them in a repeater? the `SPSiteDataQuery`? Check my else statement.

Comment: Are you using two identities or are two people working on same issue http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58401/date-from-splist-wont-show-up-in-grindview-but-the-title-shows-up

Comment: we are two thats working with same issue, but cannot solve it..

Comment: If im working with repeater control and want to show information from one list and show it, it works.. But i'm wondering, is it possible to query through three lists and show the info in a repeater?